# Eloquent Relation for items table which was created as intermediatary table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables - Books, Order, Items

I am saving the Order data(order_id,user_id) in the orders table and the book id is saved in Items table since a user can add multiple books.

Books

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id    book_code    name   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   1     abc         Book 1
   2     def         Book 2
```

Order

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id  user_id               +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
  1    1
```

Items

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id order_id book_id  quantity  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1    1        1         2
  1    1        2         3
```

I am trying to display the order details and books booked under the order id but I am confused on using the relations. 
I am successfully able to display the order details since all the data is stored in Order table.
But I not able to show the books that ordered to corresponding Order ID

#### Model Books

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Items::class);
}
```

#### Model Orders

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Items::class,'order_id');
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function user_order_details($payment_orderid)
{
    // dd($payment_orderid);  //payment_orderid  = 1
    $order_details = Orders::find($payment_orderid);
    $order_products = Orders::find($payment_orderid)->items;
    $books = Books::with('items')->get();
    dd($books);
}
```

#### Route

```
Route::get('orders', 'UserDashboardController@user_order');  // I will be fetching the user orders based on the ID from Orders table
Route::get('orders/{payment_orderid}', 'UserDashboardController@user_order_details'); // Here I would like to show the details related to the order
```

I am able to fetch the results but I am not sure how to isolate the results to the order_id.

If my database implementation is wrong and not scalable, I am open to suggestions.

In Short, I am trying to show the book details for the respective order

[image]

Note: 
If down-voting, please make sure you comment the reason. For past few questions I am being down-voted with no reason

Comment: @Rwd I have added my Orders models to the question

Comment: Which of the 3 tables that you've shown does `OrderProducts` relate to...or is it a separate table altogether?

Comment: @Rwd Sorry for being not clear, I have added more details to the question, Hope the above edit has all the info :)

Comment: What table is the `OrderProducts` model for?? You have shown 3 tables `books`, `order`, `items`...is it one of these or do you have a `order_products` table as well?

Comment: forgot to rename it :( . OrderProducts represents Items table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to query for the `Order` a second time as you've already got it on the line above i.e.

```
$order_details = Orders::find($payment_orderid);
$order_products = Orders::find($payment_orderid)->items;
```

can be:

```
$order_details = Orders::find($payment_orderid);
$order_products = $order_details->items;
```

---

Secondly, if you want to get the `books` with the order you can either make a `belongsToMany` relationship on your `Order` model or a `hasOne` relationship on your `Items` model (or both).

**BelongsToMany**

Add the following to your `Orders` model:

```php
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Books::class, 'items')
        ->withPivot('quantity')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
$order_details = Orders::find($payment_orderid);
$books = $order_details->books; //Each book with have a `pivot` property than contains  the  quantity.
```

---

**HasOne**

In your `Items` model you can add the following:

```php
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Books::class);
}
```

Then in your controller you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to get the items and books:

```
$order_details = Orders::with('items.book')->find($payment_orderid);
$order_products = $order_details->items;
```

In the above each `order_product` will have a `books` property on it i.e.

```
foreach ($order_products as $order_product) {
    $order_product->book->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very Much Bro, Took a while to get the solution working. I proceeded with BelongsToMany. I had to add order_id inorder to get the solution to work 

 public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Books::class, 'order_products', 'order_id')
            ->withPivot('quantity')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

Comment: I am very much confused with the relations in laravel. Can you please share me tutorials on the relations :)

Comment: @mightyteja This would be one of the better tutorials: https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-relationships, however, it does require a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, your items table is the pivot table for orders and books. So you can do something like this:

**Order Model**

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'items', 
      'order_id', 'book_id');
}
```

**items** is the pivot table.

In Controller:

```
public function user_order_details($payment_orderid)
{
    $order_details = Orders::find($payment_orderid);
    foreach ($order_details->books as $product)
    {
       echo $product->name;
    }
}
```